# show where the using directive is used

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using-statement

Can Visual Studio or some add-in on it tell me where each using directive is used? (Sure `organize using` tells me which is not used.)

I can manually comment each using directive and wait the vs to tell me somewhere is wrong. But that's too troublesome.

Comment: What if it is used in multiple places?

Comment: @CodyGray what's the problem?

Comment: Why do you want to know each place the referenced assemblies are used?

Comment: @Tim no pragmatic reason yet. just interested in it.

Comment: @Tim: I don't see anything that mentions referenced assemblies - the question talks about using directives, which are very different.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I see what you're saying; but you have to have reference to have a using directive, right?  Bad wording on my part though.

Comment: @Tim: Using directives deal with *namespaces*, not *assembles*. They're very different. For example, most of the classes in the System.Linq namespace are in the System.Core assembly. But multiple assemblies can contribute to a single namespace, and an assembly can contain classes within multiple namespaces.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Got it.  I was way off in what I said then.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you mean but with ReSharper 6.1 you can use [Find code dependent on module](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Dependencies_and_Referenced_Code.html) option on any of your references.